# ScrollReveal.js v2.3.2 loaded, no console errors, but doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scrollreveal.js

Using [scrollReveal.js](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollReveal.js) inside WordPress, enqueued via CDN. Retaining zero console errors but the `data-sr` values do not animate the front-end. Typing `scrollReveal` inside Chrome's inspect console shows it is initializing but will not parse animation effects.

app.js:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict( true );

(function( $ ) {
    // init scroll-reveal
    var config = {
        easing: 'hustle',
        reset:  true,
        delay:  'onload',
        vFactor: 0.90
    }
    window.sr = new scrollReveal( config );
})(jQuery);
```

Chrome Console:

`scrollReveal` input:

```
function e(e){this.docElem=t.document.documentElement,this.options=this.extend(this.defaults,e),this.styleBank=[],1==this.options.init&&this.init()}
```

Great, it's initialized, but when I append the necessary `data-sr`, or it's key values, to the front-end HTML it reports no error and yet doesn't animate.

Enqueue:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/foundation@5.5.3(js/foundation.min.js+js/vendor/jquery.js+js/vendor/modernizr.js),scrollreveal.js@0.1.2', array(), '', true );
```

Init:

```
add_action( 'init', 'source_enqueue' , 999 );
```

HTML:

```
<div role="front" data-sr>
    <main>
        <article>
            <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        the_content();
                    endwhile;
                    else:
                endif;
            ?>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Is it because I'm using `init`? Wrong jquery? I've getting zero console errors and am indeed lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding `jquery` as a dependency in `wp_enqueue_script()`?

Comment: Nope, nadda. Does it use a specific version of jquery?? I can't find documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Turns out the jsdelivr CDN package is outdated, not only on that CDN but on all CDN sites. CDN's queue `0.1.2` whereas the package uses `2.1`, so please use `bower` and enqueue through those mediums.</strike>

CDN has been updated! The following `wp_enqueue_script` works properly, along with the `noConflict()` JS file and init. Thanks to the owner of [scrollReveal.js](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollReveal.js) for assisting with the CDN error!

*Enqueue*:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll-reveal', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/scrollreveal.js/2.3.2/scrollReveal.min.js', array(), '', true );
```

*App.js*:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict( true );

(function( $ ) {

    // init scroll-reveal
    window.sr = new scrollReveal();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I updated scrollreveal on jsDelivr and enabled auto-updates http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/scrollreveal.js

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you! I can see the version is different. When did you take care of this, yesterday? Let me do some testing!